# Oracle - Query the difference between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to come up with a way in Oracle to calculate the difference between dates in days.

In short. I have two data fields "begins_at" and "ends_at" and the DATA_TYPE for those fields is "TIMESTAMP(6)"

For example. I have the following scenario:

"begins_at" value as “26-MAR-13 02.50.00.000000000 PM”

"ends_at" value as “30-MAR-13 09.25.00.000000000 PM”

I am trying to calculate the different between the two timestamps in days. Is it possible in Oracle?

I tried the following statement but threw an error:

```
Select TO_DATE(begins_at, 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS AM') - TO_DATE(ends_at, 'YYYYMMDD   HH:MI:SS AM') day_diff

From dual
```

Any tip is much appreciated.

Comment: "*but threw an error*": And which error was that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As our anonymous equine friend noted, 'threw an error' is not helpful. However, it's likely you are getting an ORA-01830, 'date format picture ends before converting entire input string', or ORA-1858, 'a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected', or something similar.

The [`to_date` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions203.htm) takes a `char` argument, so when you pass your `timestamp` field to it there is an implicit conversion happening; you're essentially doing:

```
to_date(to_char(begins_at, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS AM')
```

... only using your default NLS settings; I'm guessing you're NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to 'DD-MON-RR' for this example; the exact value will affect the error you get. The format that your `timestamp` is being given as a string does not match the format you specified for `to_date`.

You should never rely on implicit conversions, but you don't need to do a conversion here at all. `timestamp` values can be compared directly, and the results are explained [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168). Just subtracting one value form the other will give you the answer as an [`interval`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#BABIHEID) data type:

```
select ends_at - begins_at from t42;

ENDS_AT-BEGINS_AT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000004 06:35:00.000000
```

If you just want the whole day portion you can use [`extract`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions059.htm):

select extract (day from ends_at - begins_at) from t42;

```
EXTRACT(DAYFROMENDS_AT-BEGINS_AT)
---------------------------------
                                4
```

You can also treat the `timestamp` as `date` using [`cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions023.htm):

```
select cast(ends_at as date) - cast(begins_at as date) from t42;

CAST(ENDS_ATASDATE)-CAST(BEGINS_ATASDATE)
-----------------------------------------
                               4.27430556
```

I'm not sure why you're using `timestamp` at all though. The Oracle [`date` type includes a time portion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref151), down to a precision of a second. As you don't (currently) seem to be using the fractional part of the timestamp, sticking to `date` might make your manipulations simpler, but I guess it depends what you intend to do with these fields later.

Comment: You're correct in regard to the error assessment. my statement was throwing an "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" , "01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected". Sorry for not posting that in my initial question.
However, the EXTRACT function returned the values i was looking for. Thank you for your input!

Comment: What if i want to subtract two dates - 
d1 = 26th Feb 8:30PM and d2 = 28th Feb 8:15PM.
Result of d2-d1 = 1, however i want it to be 2 (diff of days).
I want, only days in date should be subtracted. But it is showing as 1.
Reason is that difference between d1 and d2 is 1 day 23 hour 45 minutes, so after round-off it will output 1 day.

I want output 2 (Only difference of days) What do i do?

Comment: @doga - that has nothing to do with this question really, you should ask a new one. But that subtraction gives 1.9895833 rather than just 1. You can use `ceil()` to force it up to 2; or `round()`. Or compare the truncated dates. Depends how you want different pairs of dates to behave.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff.  It describes `DATEDIFF`, which returns the difference in days, treating only the date values.

Comment: That link is not for the Oracle database, it's for JavaDB (Derby). Oracle's database does not have (nor need) a `datediff()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  TO_DATE('20120125 11:00:00 AM', 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS AM')
     - TO_DATE('20120120 10:00:00 AM', 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS AM') day_diff
FROM   dual
```

You can refer [this](http://oracletuts.net/tutorials/how-to-calculate-difference-between-dates-in-oracle-sql/). It will really help you

Answer (score 1):

Days, hours, minutes, seconds diff. example - copy/paste to see the output. Replace dates with your dates...:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, time_diff,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_diff) days,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_diff) hours,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_diff) minutes,
       EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_diff) seconds
  FROM
  (
   Select start_date, end_date, (end_date - start_date) time_diff
     From
     (
      Select CAST(to_date('01/01/2012 10:00:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) end_date
           , CAST(to_date('01/01/2012 07:00:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) start_date
       From dual
     )
   )
  /
```

Subtract time only example:

```
SELECT trunc(mydate / 3600) hr
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60) mnt
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60 /60) sec
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT (to_date('01/03/2012 10:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') -
           to_date('01/01/2012 07:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss')) * 86400 mydate
     FROM dual
  )
 /

HR  MNT SEC
-------------
51  0   0
```