# Subtract two dates in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate how much time spent between a job's  start and end time. Here is my query:

```
SELECT request_id, user_concurrent_program_name,
DECODE(phase_code,'C','Completed',phase_code) phase_code,
DECODE(status_code,'D', 'Cancelled' ,
'E', 'Error' , 'G', 'Warning',
'H','On Hold' , 'T', 'Terminating',
'M', 'No Manager' , 'X', 'Terminated',
'C', 'Normal', status_code) status_code,
actual_start_date, actual_completion_date, completion_text 
FROM apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v
WHERE phase_code='C' AND
status_code='C'
ORDER BY 6 DESC
```

`actual_start_date` and `actual_completion_date`'s type is `DATE` and the format is like below:

```
ACTUAL_START_DATE          ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE
3/25/2014 2:00:14 PM       3/25/2014 2:00:18 PM
```

The question is, how can i subtract these two columns and get something like `00:00:04`?

In some cases, a job can be runned for two days and i should get the result like `2 days and 00:00:02`

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755714/oracle-query-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method extracts the day component and then formats the time using `to_char()`:

```
select (trunc(ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE) || ' days and ' ||
        to_char(to_date('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE),
                'HH24:MI:SS'
               )
       )
```

In your main query, you would just add this to the end of the `select` list:

```
SELECT request_id, user_concurrent_program_name,
       DECODE(phase_code, 'C', 'Completed', phase_code) phase_code,
       DECODE(status_code, 'D', 'Cancelled' , 'E', 'Error' , 'G', 'Warning',
              'H','On Hold' , 'T', 'Terminating', 'M', 'No Manager' , 'X', 'Terminated',
              'C', 'Normal', status_code
              ) as status_code,
       actual_start_date, actual_completion_date, completion_text 
       (trunc(ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE) || ' days and ' ||
        to_char(to_date('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE),
                'HH24:MI:SS'
               )
       ) as Diff_DDHHMMSS
FROM apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v
WHERE phase_code='C' AND
status_code='C'
ORDER BY 6 DESC;
```

Comment: How can i integrate this sql query into my main query?

Comment: that kind of works but there is a problem that "hour" part is always shows the value "12" like this: "0 days and 12:00:01".

Comment: @AloneInTheDark . . . Of course.  That should be `HH24` in Oracle.

Comment: But what's the solution? Is there any other format for this? How can i prevent my sql to not get 12 value ?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark . . . The 24-hour clock returns `0` for the hour rather than `12`.  You can see it in this simplified example:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27046.